# How to achieve "LIKE '%a%a%'" with 'REGEXP' operator

Tags: mysql, regex, where-clause

Consider the following line to search for strings using the LIKE operator:

```
LIKE '%a%a%'
```

This returns when the selected string has two or more instances of the letter 'a' in the string.
How can I use REGEXP operator to only match a string with two instances of the letter `a`, no more and no less?

I have tried to read the documentation but I can't wrap my head around the descriptions for the symbols used in regular expressions

Comment: How about `.*a.*a.*`?

Comment: Yeah I just tried that! Worked like a charm. But what I wanted that I didn't specify in my question was that I wanted only two intances of the letter a, no more and no less. so I wrote ```^[^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]$```

Comment: You're a natural!

Comment: Why not simply `WHERE
 (LENGTH(<column>) - LENGTH(REPLACE(<column>, 'a', ''))) >= 2`  -> [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fRLXimFJ18HCabeJiA8vTU/0)  ... But mine suggestion and regex are both bad for indexes as they not really can be indexed unless you use a generated column

Comment: looks like there's a `*` missing right before the `$` in the regexp. unless we intend to be checking for exactly one character following the second `'a'`.  for exactly two 'a' characters anywhere in the string, `REGEXP '^[^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]*$'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^([^a]*a){2}[^a]*$
```

[Here is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xkKlvo/3)